# C# Passing image on select from one page to another xaml page in WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7

Using Photochooser Task the image has to be loaded and passed immediately to another page. But shows blank when implemented the following code:

```
private void LoadPicture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
    photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
    photoChooserTask.Show();

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}

void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        Page1 p1 = new Page1();
        p1.encodeImg.Source = bmp;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Image Loading Failed.");
    }
}
```

Please suggest in fixing the above the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try passing the the ctor?  new page1(bmp);

Comment: Is `page1` and `Page1.xaml` really the same page? It could be that these are two different instances.

Comment: yeah they are same. I've typed it wrong. But they both are same. It is Page1 p1 = new Page1();

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved it? if you haven't you could use  something like this. in your photoChooseTask handler save the bitmapImage

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = bmp;
```

and then in your Page1 you get the bitmapImage

```
BitmapImage bitmapGet = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] as BitmapImage;
```

here's how you should use this.

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            //save the bitmapImage 
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = bmp;


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Image Loading Failed.");
        }


        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

your Page1

```
      protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
      {
           //get the bitmapImage
           BitmapImage bitmapGet = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] as BitmapImage;

           //set the bitmpaImage 
           img.Source = bitmapGet;

           base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
      }
```

[More about PhoneApplicationService.Current.State :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The navigation must be done after completed event, photochooser.show() suppresses the main application thread, hence you can only pass the image stream once you get it. So, shift navigation statement to completed event handler and using isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings to store the image and get it back on second page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it is to save the image in isolateStorage first and pass the file path to your page1 as a string parameter.

page1 then could load the image anytime it needs.